# relocate svn from one to another computer-server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I never used svn so I need your help.

We have a computer (A) where svn is running now. I need to replace svn server to another computer (B) which will be as host with all files. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the Subversion ***source repository server***?

You can *dump* the Subversion repository into a file, and then *load* it into another server. The [complete directions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) are in the Subversion on line manual. It's pretty simple to do, but must be done on the source repository server.

However, this has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN which is one of many Subversion  **client** programs that talk to the server.

If you mean files that have been checked out of a Subversion source repository, and you want to place those on another server like a web server, all you need to do is to checkout (or better, use `svn export`) the files from the Subversion repository on the other machine. Hopefully, you're using either the `http://` protocol or the `svn://` protocol on your server, and not using `file://`.